# Make an image gallery with slider bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an image with slider bar. On scrolling through the slider images change. How can it be done?

Something similar to Project Update on this link :
https://www.belgradewaterfront.com/en/register-for-belgrade-waterfront-residences/

See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yFnwD/33/

```
$(".scroll-img-wrap").hide();
```

$(".scroll-img-wrap:first").show();
$( ".slider" ).slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: $(".scroll-img-wrap").length - 1,
        step: 1,

```
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $(".scroll-img-wrap").hide();
        $(".scroll-img-wrap:eq("+ui.value+")").show();
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {       
    }

});
```

The slider has to be over the images.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your problem in detail, but I may have an idea of what you want to do.

This is how I'd do mine.

First create divs for every image you want as a slider

```
<div class="pic1">

</div>
<div class="pic2">

</div>
<div class="pic3">

</div>
```

Next you will want to make them your backgrounds using css.`

```
.pic1{
  background:url(../images/background4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Then finally you'll use jQuery to make styling effects on your pic classes

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 600){
  $('.pic1').fadeIn();
}
```

});

Comment: Did you go through the link i shared? Please go the link "Progress Update" section and suggest.